# I am sending push notification from web using firebase

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification from web using firebase, but I am not able to send push notification, while I am getting only name. How can I send push notification from web using firebase help me.

This is my php code.

```
<?php
$DEFAULT_URL = 'https://pushnotificatioexample.firebaseio.com/.json';

$mytoken = $_POST['token'];
$mymessage =  $_POST['message'];
echo $mytoken;
echo '<br>'.'</br>';
echo $mymessage;

$registrationIds = array($mytoken);

$message = array
       (
        'message'   => 'My awesome message',
        'title'     => 'My awesome title',
        'subtitle'  => 'My awesome subtitle',
        'tickerText'    => 'My awesome Ticker text',
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
        'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
       );

       $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $registrationIds,
         'data' => $message
        );

       $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AIzaSyC9M4KFwqdy3vjcIBx9TNO8M7IysADbY_s',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $DEFAULT_URL);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the FCM endpoint (`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`) instead of `https://pushnotificatioexample.firebaseio.com/.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you are sending a cloud message from your service side script. According to Firebase (FCM) official documentation, you don't have to use the url from Realtime database and all. So you have to change your url

From

```
$DEFAULT_URL = 'https://pushnotificatioexample.firebaseio.com/.json';
```

TO

```
$DEFAULT_URL = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
```

See the [Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP Protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) for more details

Comment: Glad to know this is working. Kindly mark it answer and upvote it. So it will be helpful to others.